# Which Mobile Platforms are Supported by MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Which Mobile Platforms are Supported by MobileFirst Platform 6.3?

In addition, are the following services supported in the Blackberry environment:

- Updates Services?
- JSON Store?

Comment: Please be aware that the name "Worklight" is not used from 6.3 onwards. What was "Worklight Foundation" is now "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried consulting with the IBM Knowledge Center or reading the Developer Center tutorials, which list this information?

Supported environments:
iOS 6 and above
Android 2.x, 4.x and above
Windows Phone 8.x
Windows 8.x
BlackBerry 6, 7, 10.x
Mobile Web
Desktop Browser

The Worklight update service is **not** supported in BlackBerry (I assume you are referring to Direct Update)

JSONStore support does **not** extend to BlackBerry.

The full list of what is supported is in the [System Requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838).

Comment: Thanks Idan But I just need a list for new Worklight Update (Mobile First Platform).There is no documentation on Json Store for Blackberry  mobilefirstplatform on IBM knowledge Center .

Comment: The list above is for MobileFirst Platform; there is no change between Worklight 6.2 and MobileFirst 6.3 in regards to platform support. Additionally, the Knowledge Center states that JSONStore supports only iOS and Android, which means that BlackBerry is not supported...